# How to join with different database

Tags: mysql, join

I have a question table in master database

like : [image]

I have another answer table in master database

[image]

i need to fetch the answer of the college. where the problem is that the each college has its different database like college_id 1,2,3
so i need to fetch the user details from user table of that database and the question and answer are in master database.

i have config file that contain the database name e.t.c
like this

```
$dbconfig['1'] = array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user_name' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'college1'
);

$dbconfig['2'] = array(     
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user_name' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'college2'
);
```

i include the config file as `include dirname(__DIR__).'/config.php'`;
and can easily access database name like `$dbconfig[$row['college_id']]['database']` . if i have database name i can join with multiple database but i am unable to join with different database at same time please help 
me.

is there any solution in minimum query at least 2 or 3 database query to fetch the result

I edit this question again for better clearance i saved the database name in college table which contain college_id and database_name

Comment: How is your structure maintaining the relationship between questions and answers?

Comment: sorry there is also another field question_id in the answer table. i update the   second image

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the tables in this manner `db1.users`.
In this example the 'users' table on a database called 'db1'

Comment: first understand the question please remove your answer @Gadget

Comment: I have failed to understand your question, then there is a good chance that others may too. Try making your question clearer.

Comment: here i need to join on different database based on college_id

Comment: Are all databases on the same server, and can you setup a user with permissions to select from all of the college databases?

Comment: yes all databases are on same server and same user for all databases and full access

Comment: I edit my question also define college table which contains the college id and database name of the college is there any solution in that case